# Checking if NSDate is valid before usage

Tags: objective-c

In my code, I have a UIDatePicker that I use to create new NSDate objects, as well as modify some older ones. One of the things I'd like this UIDatePicker to do would be to load the value of an existing NSDate when you choose to modify it. However, doing so when the existing NSDate* doesn't point to a valid date will cause a crash. Is there some way to check whether the pointer references a valid date before loading it? Thanks for your help.

Comment: In what way would an existing NSDate be "invalid?"

Comment: Basically what Graham said, the NSDate* pointer doesn't actually point to an NSDate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, that's not really possible. What you're basically asking is "can I tell whether a pointer to some location in memory points to an active, valid Objective-C object?" and you can't know. What you should do is ensure that your picker only ever sees valid values, by discarding the invalid ones as they become useless. E.g. when some code releases a date instance, set the pointer that code is using to `nil` so it can't erroneously try to use the stale object pointer again.

Comment: Don't know why this is considered the answer.  I check for invalid dates with  'isnan(NSDate)' and if it's a 1, then yep.... it won't be a valid date.